# Allocating Memory to Structures using Operator new and sizeof

Tags: c++, data-structures, new-operator, copy-constructor

I understand that this post deals with more than one specific issue which is not ideal but they are related in a real world problem.  It would be a very beneficial learning exercise for me if someone could explain why things are not working.  please appreciate that I am a newbie and trying to work on some legacy C++ console code using VS2019.

The old code uses Classes that have members that were assigned memory individually using malloc which I understand was for C and I am supposed to use new and delete for C++.  I would like to know why my attempts to assign memory using "operator new" and "sizeof" are not working and if my attempts to simplify the code are overly optimistic.  I have spent a lot of time on this and tried to condense the issues to make the problem clearly coded and commented.  The problem as I see it is essentially:

1. How can I return the true memory requirements of a structure or class in bytes using sizeof and allocate memory during runtime with user input (I can only return the size of the class/structure pointer as opposed to the dereferenced total number of bytes pointed to)?
2. How can I use multiples of (1) given user input at runtime: i.e. (sizeof(*structure) * x) to properly assign memory?
3. After successfully assigning memory; how can I copy ranges of fields within structures without laboriously looping each member variable: is this possible with fields where the pointers reference different types with varying multiples of bytes?

Thanks for helping!

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <new>          // ::operator new
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <vector>       // std::vector

//  define structure "part"
struct part {
int* sprocket;
int* bolt;
double* cost;
double* postage;
double* packing;
double* insurance;
};
// define class "parent"
class parent {
public:
int* phone;
part* variable;
};

int main()
{

using namespace std;

// declare pointers
parent *father, *mother;
part *copy;

int size1, size2, size3, size4, size5, size6, size7, size8;
int i, l;

// get length variable at runtime
cout << "enter length" << endl;
cin >> l;

// fetch individual pointer variable sizes in bytes
size1 = sizeof(*father->variable->sprocket);    // size of int
size2 = sizeof(*father->variable->bolt);        // size of int
size3 = sizeof(*father->variable->cost);        // size of double
size4 = sizeof(*father->variable->postage);     // size of double
size5 = sizeof(*father->variable->packing);     // size of double
size6 = sizeof(*father->variable->insurance);   // size of double
size7 = sizeof(*father);                        // size of total struct
size8 = sizeof(*copy);                          // size of total struct
// print these to console for checking
cout << "sizes in bytes"                         << endl;
cout << "sizeof int sprocket is:"       << size1 << endl;
cout << "sizeof int bolt is:"           << size2 << endl;
cout << "sizeof double cost is:"        << size3 << endl;
cout << "sizeof double postage is:"     << size4 << endl;
cout << "sizeof double packing is:"     << size5 << endl;
cout << "sizeof double insurance is:"   << size6 << endl;
cout << "sizeof 'father' is:"           << size7 << endl;
cout << "sizeof 'copy' is:"             << size8 << endl;

//  This is the output to the console:

//  enter length
//  10
//  sizes in bytes
//  sizeof int sprocket is : 4
//  sizeof int bolt is : 4
//  sizeof double cost is : 8
//  sizeof double postage is : 8
//  sizeof double packing is : 8
//  sizeof double insurance is : 8
//  sizeof 'father' is : 8
//  sizeof 'copy' is : 24


/* cannot work out a way of finding total number of bytes associated with
structure or class /*

/* I want to avoid doing this!!! */

//father->phone             = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * l);
//father->variable->bolt    = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * l);
//father->variable->................... etc etc etc

/* and instead do this */

father = (parent*) :: operator new (sizeof(parent) * 2 * l);
if (father == NULL)
cout << "error assigning memory to variable." << endl;

copy = (part*) :: operator new (sizeof(part) * l);
if (copy == NULL)
cout << "error assigning memory to copy." << endl;

/*  but cannot seem to get the memory assignment right!!! 
and get a "write access violation" here which I'm certain 
is due to the "new" allocation above  */

/* this loop only to populate data in "father" to check memory
allocation and data for checking copying later*/    
for (i = 0; i < (2 * l); i++) {
father->phone[i]                = i;
father->variable->sprocket[i]   = i;
father->variable->bolt[i]       = i;
father->variable->cost[i]       = i * 0.3; // multiply by 0.3 to give double
father->variable->postage[i]    = i * 0.3; // multiply by 0.3 to give double
father->variable->packing[i]    = i * 0.3; // multiply by 0.3 to give double
father->variable->insurance[i]  = i * 0.3; // multiply by 0.3 to give double
}

/*  I wish to copy a range (in this example half user input l) from 
the "part" structure of "father" to the part structure 
pointed to by "copy" but would like to do it elegantly 
as follows rather than loop through each 
member pointer.
        
I'd like to assign the new pointer "copy" to another "parent" object 
later in code.  This avoids a lot of complication in further modifying 
the legacy code hence cannot pass class object as argument 3*/

//std::copy(father->variable, father->variable + (l/2), copy.begin());

// later in code.........

//initialize "mother"
//mother->variable = copy;

}
```

Comment: You already `#include <vector>`, why are you starting to mess with `new` manually? Also all those pointers for plain member variables in your classes look weird. Why are you using pointers there? Are these meant to be `std::vector<double>` members?

Comment: Sorry if that is inappropriate: like I said I'm learning.

Comment: I am afraid you need to start from scratch again, and rethink you class design thoroughly. Try to use no pointers at all.

Comment: I'm afraid your comments are not very helpful.  You could respond to everything ever posted on here as "start from scratch again." If I was capable of getting this right in the first place I wouldn't need to ask for help.  Can you please help me with the question of how to pass the correct sizeof variable to the memory assignment?  The pointers are representative of the code I am working with: I have to deal with such an arrangement.

Comment: Your impression of mine takes you wrong. I really say that extraordinarily rare, but what you have looks so screwed, that I am convinced it's better to start over. For starters I believe that `part` should look like: `struct part {
int sprocket;
int bolt;
double cost;
double postage;
double packing;
double insurance;
};`, the use of pointers there literally makes no sense (unless you can explain with a good reason).

Comment: Rather than making a structure of arrays, consider making an array of structures. This keeps all of the data for one instance of the structure in a contiguous block and all of the instances of the structure in one big contiguous block, providing a regularity to the data that a modern computer can often exploit for huge performance gains. Plus the book keeping is a lot easier on the human brain. For example, it's much easier to sort the data structure by structure, than it is to sort the data by one of the many arrays and ensure the other arrays are also rearranged accordingly.

Comment: Note: While a phone number is a sequence of digits, it has more in common with a string than it does a number. When was the last time you performed arithmetic on a phone number? Does it make sense to add June and Meagan's phone numbers? If you're not using a number as a number, it's probably not really a number.

Comment: Ah right!  Yes I get that: good idea thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` deals in raw bytes only.  `new` deals in objects, and `new[]` deals in arrays of objects.  The size of the object is handled for you by the compiler, so you don't need to use `sizeof()` manually at all, ie these statements in C:

```c
father->phone             = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * l);
father->variable->bolt    = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * l);
father->variable->................... etc etc etc

...

free(father->variable->................... etc etc etc);
free(father->variable->bolt);
free(father->phone);
```

Would translate to this in C++ using `new[]`:

```cpp
father->phone             = new int[l];
father->variable->bolt    = new int[l];
father->variable->................... etc etc etc

...

delete[] father->variable->................... etc etc etc;
delete[] father->variable->bolt;
delete[] father->phone;
```

However, you really should consider using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly.  Let it handle the memory management for you.

Comment: Excellent: thanks Remy that's exactly the kind of direction I'm looking for to tackle this.  I am trying to work with old code some of which may well have been written in C so that is probably where some of my misunderstanding is coming from regarding the different methods of memory allocation: appreciate it!

Comment: The code you have shown is so convoluted and error prone, I agree with πάνταῥεῖ that it really needs to be rewritten from scratch.  C++ is not C, there are things done in C that are handled in much better ways in C++. *Avoiding* the use of `new` directly is one of them. Utilize automatic storage instead of dynamic storage when possible. Utilize standard containers when dealing with dynamic arrays/list. Utilize constructors and destructors when managing dynamic resources manually.

Comment: The code I posted was an attempt to take elements of a much bigger project that I am wrestling with and present my logic with a very basic representation.  The original project was written a long time ago by someone else and uses classes that manipulate memory using malloc, realloc etc and make extensive use of pointers to store/manipulate large datasets.  I am adding facilities to this old code whilst also learning to program!  I apologise to you and πάνταῥεῖ if it looked like a bit of a car crash but I have learned already to go with the more modern tools so it has already been worth it!